# How to parse json response in the shell script?

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, wget

I am working with bash shell script. I need to execute an URL using shell script and then parse the json data coming from it.

This is my URL - `http://localhost:8080/test_beat` and the responses I can get after hitting the URL will be from either these two -

```
{"error": "error_message"}
{"success": "success_message"}
```

Below is my shell script which executes the URL using wget.

```
#!/bin/bash

DATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 http://localhost:8080/test_beat)
#grep $DATA for error and success key
```

Now I am not sure how to parse json response in $DATA and see whether the key is success or  error. If the key is success, then I will print a message "success" and print $DATA value and exit out of the shell script with zero status code but if the key is error, then I will print "error" and print $DATA value and exit out of the shell script with non zero status code.

How can I parse json response and extract the key from it in shell script?

I don't want to install any library to do this since my JSON response is fixed and it will always be same as shown above so any simpler way is fine.

**Update:-**

Below is my final shell script -

```
#!/bin/bash

DATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 http://localhost:8080/tester)
echo $DATA
#grep $DATA for error and success key
IFS=\" read __ KEY __ MESSAGE __ <<< "$DATA"
case "$KEY" in
success)
    exit 0
    ;;
error)
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Does this looks right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS= read -d '' DATA < temp.txt  ## Imitates your DATA=$(wget ...). Just replace it.
while IFS=\" read -ra LINE; do
    case "${LINE[1]}" in
    error)
        # ERROR_MSG=${LINE[3]}
        printf -v ERROR_MSG '%b' "${LINE[3]}"
        ;;
    success)
        # SUCCESS_MSG=${LINE[3]}
        printf -v SUCCESS_MSG '%b' "${LINE[3]}"
        ;;
    esac
done <<< "$DATA"
echo "$ERROR_MSG|$SUCCESS_MSG"  ## Shows: error_message|success_message
```

***** `%b` expands backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument.

---

Update as I didn't really get the question at first. It should simply be:

```
IFS=\" read __ KEY __ MESSAGE __ <<< "$DATA"
[[ $KEY == success ]]  ## Gives $? = 0 if true or else 1 if false.
```

And you can examine it further:

```
case "$KEY" in
success)
    echo "Success message: $MESSAGE"
    exit 0
    ;;
error)
    echo "Error message: $MESSAGE"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Of course similar obvious tests can be done with it:

```
if [[ $KEY == success ]]; then
    echo "It was successful."
else
    echo "It wasn't."
fi
```

From your last comment it can be simply done as

```
IFS=\" read __ KEY __ MESSAGE __ <<< "$DATA"
echo "$DATA"  ## Your really need to show $DATA and not $MESSAGE right?
[[ $KEY == success ]]
exit  ## Exits with code based from current $?. Not necessary if you're on the last line of the script.
```

Comment: Thanks konsolebox but I also need to have exit status code. If the key is success, then exit status code should be 0 but if it is error, then exit status code should be non zero. How would I do that as well?

Comment: nopes, I mean to say, if the key is success, `echo $DATA; exit 0` and if key is error, then `echo $DATA; exit 2`. Something like this?

Comment: sorry I was away for a while. I have updated the question. can you see whether I got everything correctly in my shell script?

Comment: Yes it seems correct enough. Just one thing. You should quote $DATA to be safe from pathname expansion: `echo "$DATA"`

Comment: There's another: What would you want the return value if no data was caught? e.g. Download errors, invalid data, etc. Do you want to `exit 1` for anything besides success? Or perhaps do `exit 2` for any other that's not `success` nor `error`. If so you can add `*) exit 2 ;;`. On the other hand if you just want to exit with `0` for success, and `1` for anything besides it, just consider the last part of my answer. It's simple enough.

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to be using any more complicated json from the shell and you can install additional software, [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is going to be your friend.

So, for example, if you want to just extract the error message if present, then you can do this:

```
$ echo '{"error": "Some Error"}' | jq ".error"
"Some Error"
```

If you try this on the success case, it will do:

```
$echo '{"success": "Yay"}' | jq ".error"
null
```

The main advantage of the tool is simply that it fully understands json.  So, no need for concern over corner cases and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash 3.2+ without dependencies (such as jq, python, grep, etc.):

```
source <(curl -s -L -o- https://github.com/lirik90/bashJsonParser/raw/master/jsonParser.sh)
JSON='{"error": "error_message"}'
JSON=$(minifyJson "$JSON")
echo "Message is: $(parseJson "$JSON" error)"
```

[Try it](https://replit.com/@lirik90/bashJsonParser).

Answer (score 0):

You probably already have python installed, which has json parsing in the standard library. Python is not a great language for one-liners in shell scripts, but here is one way to use it:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 http://localhost:8080/test_beat)

if python -c '
import json, sys
exit(1 if "error" in json.loads(sys.stdin.read()) else 0)' <<<"$DATA"
then
  echo "SUCCESS: $DATA"
else
  echo "ERROR: $DATA"
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

- that you don't want to use JSON libraries.
- and that the response you're parsing is simple and the only thing you care about is the presence of substring `"success"`, I suggest the following **simplification**:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

wget -O - -q -t 1 http://localhost:8080/tester | grep -F -q '"success"'
exit $?
```

- `-F` tells `grep` to search for a fixed (literal) string.
- `-q` tells `grep` to produce no output and instead only reflect via its *exit code* whether a match was found or not.
- `exit $?` simply exits with `grep`'s exit code (`$?` is a special variable that reflects the most recently executed command's exit code).

Note that if you all you care about is *whether* `wget`'s output contains `"success"`, the above pipeline will do - no need to capture `wget`'s output in an aux. variable.