# How to extract a value of a Map String

Tags: sh

I have this String value which is a Map of user to password

```
'{"userJohn":"1234","userLinda":"9876"}'
```

the string has a single quate from each side.

How can I extract the password of say, **userLinda**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse json response in the shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644520/how-to-parse-json-response-in-the-shell-script)

Comment: Are you sure the _value_ contains single quotes? You can remove them with a simple [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
# fishell
 ~ echo '\'{"userJohn":"1234","userLinda":"9876"}\'' | sed 's/^\'//' | sed 's/\'$//' | jq '.userLinda'
"9876"


# bash zsh
~ echo "'"'{"userJohn":"1234","userLinda":"9876"}'"'" | sed "s/^'//" | sed "s/'$//" | jq '.userLinda'
"9876"
```

Comment: `echo '\'` emits a literal double quote; that's hardly what you wanted to demonstrate.

Comment: What do you mean,It is single quote on my computer

Comment: Perhaps you transcribed it incorrectly. Demo: https://ideone.com/0mJy26

Comment: yeah, I get it, i use fishell, it is fine, I will change the answer

Comment: Adding to the confusion, I meant a literal backslash. Sorry and thanks for the update. Perhaps the Fish solution should not be at the top of the answer, though - the question is clearly tagged [tag:sh]